# cvs login issue - how to restrict a user from cvs login

Tags: cvs, cvsnt

Is there any way to restrict particular users from cvs login or allow only particular users to login.
We are using pserver connection for the cvs login and the authentication is done via LDAP.

Thanks in advance.

Selvi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [chacl command](http://www.cvsnt.org/manual/html/chacl.html) to set up access control.